# dialogs.less file is not working

Tags: css, dialog, less, focus

I had a problem with the checkbox focus while pressing the Tab Key. But it got resolved by using **dialog.css** file by using the below code:

```
.delete-for-reals img,
.delete-for-reals input:focus {
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  width: 15px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

But the product wants to resolve this issue through **dialogs.less** file. When I used the exact above code in **less** css file, the focus is not showing in the checkbox while I'm pressing the Tab Key. Is that I need to change anything for the less css particularly? I'm new to the less css. This Problem is only occuring in firefox and IE. Its working fine with the Chrome.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? How would you describe "working"? Which product?

Comment: Describe this in the question itself (edit the question) so that other answerers have a full context and know what you want. Comments could be deleted.

Comment: I don't know anything about dialog/less/css - just helping you write a better question so others can help you.